# Regularity Enforces Trivial $\in$-Isomorphisms

Tags: set-theory

Theorem 6.7. in Jech's Set Theory:

> Assume Regularity. Let $T_1, T_2$ be transitive classes and let the bijection $\pi \colon T_1 \to T_2$ satisfy $u \in v \implies \pi u \in \pi v$. Then $\pi u = u$ for all $u \in T_1$ (and hence $T_1 = T_2$).

I have proved this statement independently and differently to Jech's proposed argument; of course I also want to understand his proof:

> By $\in$-induction. Suppose $\pi z = z$ for all $z \in x \in T_1$. Then $x \subseteq \pi x$ because $z = \pi z \in \pi x$. Let $y \in \pi x$. Since $T_2$ is transitive, there is some z for which $\pi z = y$. **Since $\pi z \in \pi x$, we have $z \in x$**, and so $y = \pi z = z$. Thus $y \in x$.

I absolutely fail to see why the bold assertion follows (what obvious detail am I missing?). Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in the statement of the theorem.  It should say $u \in v \iff \pi u \in \pi v$ instead of $u \in v \implies \pi u \in \pi v$.  The line in question then follows immediately from this assumption.

The theorem is not true the way you wrote it.  For instance, let $T_1=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ and $T_2=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ and let $\pi(\emptyset)=\emptyset$, $\pi(\{\emptyset\})=\{\emptyset\}$, and $\pi(\{\{\emptyset\}\})=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.

Comment: I see you Think Alike ...

Comment: Hah, well, it's not too surprising we came up with the same counterexample as it is the minimal one.

Comment: Thank you. Might be time to replace the printer if half the logical implications get lost in transit... (and also time to find the mistake in my "proof")

Answer (score 3):

By your choice of $y$ and $z$, you have $y\in\pi(x)$ and $\pi(z)=y$. Plug the latter into the former to conclude $\pi(z)\in\pi(x)$.

The $\implies$ in the assumption for $\pi$ must be a typo for $\iff$. Otherwise this would be a counterexample to the claim:
$$ T_1 = \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\}\} \\
T_2 = \{ \varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\} $$
with the "obvious" $\pi$.

Therefore $\pi(z)\in\pi(x)$ implies $z\in x$.

Comment: Thank you. I have Eric's answer, as it appeared first, but it goes without saying this acceptance extends to your answer as well.

Comment: @user480881: I think you may be reading the timestamps backwards (not that the precise position of the checkmark matters, seeing how both I and Eric have more imaginary internet points than we'll ever need...)

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't notice the timestamps. Eric's answer was displayed above yours and the argument is similar (equivalent?), so I just went ahead and accepted his. But since you're ok with it...

Comment: @user480881: (The arguments are pretty much identical, except for the typographical choice of $\emptyset$ or $\varnothing$.) The default sorting of answers does not reflect posting order, but is in order of highest-voted answers first, with ties broken randomly at each page load.